# md5sum complaining about carriage return characters

Tags: windows, bash, macos, newline, carriage-return

I'm getting an error while trying to check md5sums of some downloaded files. My guess is that the checksum was computed on a Windows machine while I'm trying to compare them on MacOS, because `md5sum` seems to be complaining about carriage return characters. Any quick way to overcome this?

```
md5sum -c file_with_checksums.txt
: FAILED open or read
md5sum: 'some_file.txt'$'\r': No such file or directory
```

Comment: The default MacOS tool is called `md5` and has no `-c` switch. Please clarify what you are doing.

Comment: `\r` is carriage return, not newline.

Comment: The error refers to another file than you're showing in the input, and it looks like the file that's actually being checked has a carriage return _in its name_.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi You're right. My `md5sum` was installed from `coreutils-8.25` (some time ago, so I didn't remember that). What I'm trying to do is to `read MD5 sums from the FILEs and check them` as per `md5sum` manual page.

Comment: @Paul Hodges. Thanks, edited question.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I guess the file name does not actually include it. Windows uses `\r\n` as end of line, so a MacOS system using only `\n` would erroneously attach the leftover `\r` to the name.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Yes, I bet you're right, `file_with_checksums.txt` contains carriage returns.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments to the question, the characters at the end of file names are for carriage return (`\r`).

The more straightforward way to solve this issue is to use `tr` or `sed` and pipe to `md5sum`:

```
cat file_with_checksums.txt | tr -d '\r' | md5sum -c -
```

or:

```
sed  $'s/\r//' file_with_checksums.txt | md5sum -c -
```

Comment: Confirmed in my case of Oracle Dockerfile https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/b72e964f87730d5c0cb870b2c863e0a022d7ede6/OracleWebLogic/dockerfiles/buildDockerImage.sh#L50 . The `$'\r': No such file or directory` error happens with checksum file pulled into Windows and run in MINGW64. This answer is really helpful.